# How to add views to layout from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Based on user inputs I'm dynamically adding many textviews to a relative layout in a loop.

The problem is that as the number of tv increase the amount of time it takes to build the layout also increases to the point when the user will get the "wait/force close" message.

I know this due to being on the main UI thread but as far as I know I cannot add views to a layout asynchronously, say in doInBackground as you get "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" error.

Each new tv is either to the right_of or below the previous tv, calculated in the loop, so I cannot move the addview statement into AsyncTask onPostExecute.

Is there a way to add the tvs, in the for loop, to a layout while using AsyncTask?

This is how it needs to be done:

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){ ....

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){  ...

        while (yCoord + CellSizeH < b2.getHeight()) {
             while (xCoord + CellSizeW < b2.getWidth() ) {

                tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setTextSize(DisplayCellSizeH * 0.5f);
                tv.setWidth(DisplayCellSizeW);
                tv.setHeight(DisplayCellSizeH);
                tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...
                }

                //this will error so needs to be in onPostExecute
                thelayout.addView(tv, params1);
              }
          }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){ ...
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: you are not supposed to access the View from a diff thread

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent. You should be running out of heap space before you hit an ANR, suggesting that you are doing some of the wrong work on the main application thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to AsyncTask doinbaground allow the views to be adding during the async task loop

```
Viewchart.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        thelayout.addView(tv, params1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what [ListViews](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) are for. Putting in a custom adapter will work. Essentially, each row in the table will load only what is required to get it to work.

Essentially, the ListView is your container, and you create an adapter which populates the data appropriately. You add a custom adapter to the ListView, and you're set. Here's a simple layout of an Adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter (Context c) {
    }

    public int getCount() {
        /Number of rows
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //Probably not required for your applications
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //Probably not required for your applications
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Create a view here, and return it.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, listviews is not going to help in this instance. My relative layout needs to both zoom and pan off screen.

Answer (score 1):

This code from one of implementation in some project , try it

declare your layout and the activity you work on it

```
LinearLayout asyncLayout;
Activity myactivity;
```

and in `onCreate`

```
asyncLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.asyncLayout);
    myactivity= this;

    new LoadData().execute();
```

then your Async implementation

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        myactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                     TextView text = new TextView(List_Activity.this);
                     text.setWidth(40);
                     text.setHeight(20);
                     text.setText("text : " + i);
                     asyncLayout.addView(text);
                }


            }
        });

                    return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    }
```

feed me back

Comment: Thanks but I found the same solution 5 minutes before you posted this, so answered the question myself, see below.